# If $f$ takes $[-1,1]$ onto $[-1,1]$ then $f^{-1}(\{f(0)\})=\{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, examples-counterexamples, inverse

Consider the statement:

> If $f$ takes $[-1,1]$ onto $[-1,1]$ then $f^{-1}(\{f(0)\})=\{0\}$.

My book tells me this is suppose to be false, but I don't understand why.

We know:

If $f:X\to Y$ has an inverse function, then $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ and $f(f^{-1}(y))=y$ for all $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. From this definition, it would appear that our original statement is true.

If this is indeed false, do I need to find a function $f$ such that $[-1,1]$ onto $[-1,1]$ can't be inverted?

Comment: Perhaps it was instead meant that $f^{-1}(f(0))=\{0\}$?

Comment: Yes, it was. Let me fix that.

Comment: Ah, then the notation $f^{-1}$ does not necessary refer to an inverse function, but the pre-image.

Comment: You probably mean $f^{-1}(\{f(0)\})$, not $f^{-1}(f(\{0\}))$.

Comment: I wish I did, that is why I was so confused. It specifically has {0}.

Comment: Of course "it has {0}" on the RHS. No problem with *that*.

Comment: It has {0} on the LHS as well.

Comment: Please do not rollback the modifications made to correct your post. (Or give us a source where the version you typed is given.)

Comment: An Introduction to Analysis by William R. Wade Fourth Edition. Page 34 problem 1.5.0 part d. I changed it back because the edit changed the problem. Whether the braces outside the $f$, or inside, make a difference, I do not know. It was changed to what I saw as a different problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counter example: $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$. Then, $f:[-1,1]\to[-1,1]$ is onto

[image]

but $f^{-1}(f(0))=f^{-1}(0)=\{-1,0,1\}.$

Answer (score 2):

$f$ may not necessarily have an inverse because it may not necessarily be one-to-one. Consider functions $g:[-1,0]\to[-1,1]$ and $h:(0,1]\to[-1,1]$ where $g,h$ are onto, and let $f=g\cup h$

Comment: I understand that this leads to $f=g \cup h =\{-1,0,1\}$. How do I use that to show $f^{-1}(f(\{0\}))=\{0\}$?

Comment: Here we have at least two elements that map to 0. Particularly at least one from g and at least one from h.